# Impossible to visualize display language with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, cultureinfo, currentculture

I currently make a program in vb.net which needs to know what is the DISPLAY language in windows.

I try to visualize it using : 
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name

But when I use it, the value equals to null. The only language I succeed to visualize is the INSTALL language which isn't the same than the current one.

Did someone already faces this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean visualize? What code are you using?

Comment: I mean, get the value in a variable, I would like to have "en-US" for example.

Comment: Well since you haven't provided any context or code, the only thing I can say is that `MsgBox(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)` returns "en-US" for me. So it's not broken or null. You might need to specify the thread?

Comment: When I use it in a message box, I got a message box which appears with no content.

Comment: Well gee, without any code at all to illustrate the problem or how you are doing anything, we cant even know if you are using MessageBox correctly (its not a debug tool after all).  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I would like to give more information about my code, the problem is that I not really use a IDE like visual studio or someting like that. I use UiPath Studio which is a progiciel, it is pseudo-code. My message box is an activity and I can put vb.net code into it to visual something. So I put : System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name into my activity